# Hearer document.addEventListener (function () {function as in the example

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

I'm having a little problem that I do not know how to solve, I'm trying to run an example that is in ngcordova site but without success.

When I use the plugin $ cordovaInAppBrowser.open ({...

it usually works but to place the event listener

document.addEventListener (function () {... it does not open the link

in cordovaInAppBrowser.open $ ({...

I need to use the event listener to use the functions

necessary application, I can not understand what is

going on I am using the example without touching on

anything

Can someone help me ?

Here is the sample code

```
module.controller('ThisCtrl', function($cordovaInAppBrowser) {

  var options = {
      location: 'yes',
      clearcache: 'yes',
      toolbar: 'no'
    };

  document.addEventListener(function () {
    $cordovaInAppBrowser.open('http://ngcordova.com', '_blank', options)
      .then(function(event) {
        // success
      })
      .catch(function(event) {
        // error
      });


    $cordovaInAppBrowser.close();

  }, false);

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstart', function(e, event){

  });

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loadstop', function(e, event){
    // insert CSS via code / file
    $cordovaInAppBrowser.insertCSS({
      code: 'body {background-color:blue;}'
    });

    // insert Javascript via code / file
    $cordovaInAppBrowser.executeScript({
      file: 'script.js'
    });
  });

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:loaderror', function(e, event){

  });

  $rootScope.$on('$cordovaInAppBrowser:exit', function(e, event){

  });

});
```

Only need to open an external page but document.addEventListener listener (function () {not let me open and I need him to be present as in the sample code to work correctly.

Comment: Seems you need to add an event type in addEventListener

Comment: yes I added click kind but the problem in my code it does not return anything to me from the window that opens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only solution I found was this direct opening the window and making the necessary changes directly to the external page, thank the help of all.

Here's the code I used

```
var options = {
       location: 'yes'
       clearcache 'yes'
       toolbar: 'no'
    };

   


$ Scope.ircadastro = function () {

$ CordovaInAppBrowser.open ('url', '_blank', options)

    }
```